# How to access request object in AfterCreate - waterline , sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, waterline

I have 2 models Newspaper.js and Reader.js

```
// Newspaper
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    title: {
      type: 'string'
    },
  }
};
```

and reader

```
//Reader
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    // In case if the message is poll, it has options field which enumerates choices.
    title: {
      type: 'string'
    },
  }
};
```

And a model to store many to many relationship between them

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    newsPaper: {
      model: 'newsPaper'
    },
    reader: {
      model: 'reader'
    }
  }
};
```

My client sends me a call when ever a new reader joins with multiple subscriptions and I get news papers as array in my call.

I have list of news papers in afterValidate call of reader but no ID of reader created. I get ID of new reader created in AfterCreate but no newspapers.

How can I create a relationship after creating an entry of reader?

Comment: You'll have to post your code where you're actually handling the incoming calls as well.

Comment: I am using blueprint method. No code written in controller while new reader creation.

Comment: OK, then I don't understand at all what you need help with. Can you reword your question maybe?

Comment: I intend to ask for elegant way to store new reader along with the map of reader and newspaper using blueprint methods. I wish to know if I can solve this without overwriting blueprint method of create.